# jquery code working on localhost but not on remote server

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, loading

Ok I am working on a website which is below:

http://clinicasdefertilidadenlima.pe/demo/

If you open it and click on link "Enviale un correo" just below the picture, it should open a contact form which is not displaying. I used Firebug to see what's wrong and in Console it shows status 200 OK in red color and doesn't display form. And Firebug also doesn't display "Response" tab where I can see response received.

The above URL works fine on localhost.

This form is exact copy of the one working on live site below
http://www.clinicasdefertilidadenlima.pe/

The live site form displays fine and Firbug Console says 200 OK but in normal black color. And it display "Response" tab where I can see response received.

The only difference between forms of live and demo site is, I have added a new field in demo form and also updated its backend PHP code. That's it!

Now for the life of me I am unable to fix this issue. I have been trying for more than an hour but in vain.

Comment: $ is not defined
$(function(){

http://www.clinicasdefertilidadenlima.pe/demo/contact_doctor.php?fn_name=contact_doctor&doc_id=14&doc_email=morofe210-s@yahoo.com&height=400&width=600&random=1334247842560

Comment: I don't see $ not defined (it may be updated since the comment) but the rest of the JS resources all have bad paths, producing a string of 404s.

Comment: @RTulley
But this error is also shown on live site although it loads fine.

Comment: @GregPettit
But this error is also shown on live site although it loads fine.

Comment: Be that as it may, if you have 404s on 9 files, you have something to fix even if it's not related to this exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make request to the same domain. Add www to the url and it will be work. Try: http://www.clinicasdefertilidadenlima.pe/demo/

To avoid this problem add this to your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^clinicasdefertilidadenlima\.pe$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.clinicasdefertilidadenlima\.pe\/$1" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're running into an Access-Control-Allow-Origin issues - you'll need to configure apache to allow requests from the domain without the www subdomain. You can change this setting in your .htaccess file.

[More info on this here](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/02/04/adding-access-control-allow-origin-to-server-for-cross-domain-scripting/)